# Нужен поток, который приостановит другие потоки

Tags: python, многопоточность

Доброе время суток. Парсер получает 100 новостей и раскидывает все по трём потокам на запись. Это я уже организовал, каждый поток принимает 100 новостей и записывает их в JSON формате в один и тот же файл, блокировки, когда один из потоков записывает, тоже есть. Задача заключается в организации последнего потока, который будет блокировать все три потока при каком-то действии от пользователя и смотреть то, что эти потоки уже записали в файл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и записывает их в JSON формате в один и тот же файл

А зачем в данной задаче использовать потоки? На момент записи два других потока заблокированы? В единицу времени у Вас работает только один поток на запись?

> Задача заключается в организации ... потока, который будет блокировать все три потока

Давайте скажем, что это еще один поток (а может быть использовать главный поток, а то он вроде после получения данных больше ничего не делает и помер или по хорошему повис на .join), которыq проверяет нажатие на клавиатуре кнопrb (а проще просто воткнуть time.sleep и подождать 1 секунду) и остановит потоки.

Это можно сделать несколькими способами:

- Попросить операционную систему заморозить поток (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-suspendthread), но такой дизайн систем считают плохим тоном
- Использовать механизм синхронизации (разновижность блокировки)

Разновижностей блокировок на все вкусы и цвета:

- Блокировка - Lock - кто захватил тот и работает, а остальные ждут
- Многовходовая блокировка - RLock - кто захватил может еще раз захватить, но и освободить столько же раз должен (см. рекурсию и т.д.)
- Условие - Condition - все ждут (wait) пока выполнено условие
- Семафор - Semafore - ждут несколько / работают несколько
- Событие - Event - ждем (wait) пока кто-то не отпустит (set)
- Барьер - Barier - отпустит когда все лошади подойдут к барьеру (на скачках)

Выбирай удобный тебе механизм.

С другой стороны у тебя жу уже есть одна блокировка и если ее захватит кто-то четвертый, то остальные "писатели" будут заблокированы.

Comment: Да, домашняя задачка по ОС. Если честно, то я понимаю,  что лучше 3 потока в очереди, чем 1, т.к. могут чаще быть в исполнении, чем на ожидании. Скорее всего, что подойдёт механизм условия. Спасибо!

Comment: Еще раз прочитай мой ответ. В твоей задаче потоки не нужны в принципе (что в три потока писать с блокировкой, что в один поток общее время будет одинаковое, а то и больше, так как потоки и блокировки ещё обслуживать надо операионке). Диск у тебя узкое место, а не CPU, но так как задача академическая, то и ладно. Тебе проще захватить блокировку, которая у тебе блокирует запись в файл, а не городить еще один Condition.